# Windows 10 no events no update history, virus?

Tags: windows-10, virus

Made up a new windows 10 computer 2 months ago after last computer got infected by cryptolocker by inexperienced user. New computer has been in use daily since without problem, however was left on for 2 days around 2 days ago, which at 3am seems to have reinstalled windows..?

A new windows.old folder now exists, old programs are still installed but some - including avast - were not working correctly (all working now), system settings like password to login have now returned, there is now no event logs or update history prior to 2 days ago. sfc fine. No obvious viruses.

I'm not sure what's going on, is it likely reinfected? What can I check for further?

Comment: You re-installed windows,  the history is stored in the registry and that got wiped out so, of course, your history is empty.  It is not obvious why, but either a system reset or re-install of windows occurred.

Comment: Best option is to back up important files and clean reinstall W10.

Comment: Here is my guess.  When you installed Windows 10 you installed build 10240, a few days later, Windows saw that Version 1511 should be installed and did so.  These major updates (more or less) reinstall Windows when they are installed.  All your files and programs should be there, unless, they were known to be incompatiable with Windows 10.  This is to be expected, I have answered, many questions similar  to this with that exact response/answer.  **is it likely reinfected?** - Nope; I can say with 100% certaintity this didnt happen.

Answer (score -1):

Could be that your system was taken over during the late hours of the night. That would explain an entire re installation of your OS. I would check with malware bytes if you have any rootkits installed on your system.

Comment: Can you broaden on how this could happen